# Identifying a complex number

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am creating a calculator application for all types of mathematical algorithms. However, I want to identify if a root is complex and then have an exception for it.
I came up with this:

```
if x == complex():
    print("Error 05: Complex Root")
```

However, nothing is identified or printed when I run the app, knowing that `x` is a complex root.

Comment: Are the indents exactly as in your question? Is there any error? Could you add `else` part of `if` statement? What about `complex()`? Shouldn't you pass an argument to it and return `True` or `False`?

Comment: Wait a second - what if a complex root is not an error?  Sometimes that's the right answer.  Are you sure it should be flagged as an error?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you want to check if a variable is of complex type you can use [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance).  For example,

```
x = 5j
if isinstance(x, complex):
    print 'X is complex'
```

prints

```
X is complex
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> isinstance(1j, complex)
True
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
if isinstance(x, complex):
    print("Error 05: Complex Root")
```

This prints error for `2 + 0j`, `3j`, but does not print anything for `2`, `2.12` etc.

Also think about throwing an error (`ValueError` or `TypeError`) when the variable is complex.

Answer (score 5):

In NumPy v1.15, a function is included: [numpy.iscomplex(](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/lib/type_check.py#L185-L218)x[)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/lib/type_check.py#L185-L218)

where `x` is the number, that is to be identified.

Comment: There is also `numpy.iscomplexobj`, which is what I needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be to do,

```
if type(x) == complex():
    print("Error 05: Complex Root")
```

As others have pointed out, isinstance works too